# Adding a test for "internet down" in Visual Studio Test Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, integration-testing

I have a testing project in Visual Studio 2010.

One of the tested classes is supposed to send some internet requests.

I want to write a test like:

```
[TestMethod()]
[ExpectedException(typeof(InternetDownException))]
public void ThrowsInternetDownExceptionWhenNoInternet()
{
    // How do I fake internet down??
    target.Connect();  // this is supposed to throw
}
```

It is important to make clear that this is not a strict unit test project, since it accesses the internet (and the filesystem in some methods), but I would like to have these tests anyway, in a project separated from my other frequently running, true unit test project.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up successfully using the methods below. Note that I use a "hardcoded" connection name ("Conexão Local" in my case), but there are methods to find the name of active connection (left to the reader ;o)

```
    public static void DisableInternet()
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(
            "netsh",
            "interface set interface name=\"Conexão local\" admin=disabled"
        );
        process.StartInfo = psi;
        process.Start();
    }

    public static void EnableInternet()
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(
            "netsh",
            "interface set interface name=\"Conexão local\" admin=enabled"
        );
        process.StartInfo = psi;
        process.Start();
    }
```

(also, looking at it now, it would be easy to DRY these methods a lot...)